# Overlapping box with infinite edge coordinate

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I try to understand how does overlapping box with infinity works

Why does the following exemple doesn't work. It works fine except when i try to introduce two infinite values.

This exemple should return true.

```
SELECT box '((1,1),(infinity, 1))' && box '((2, 1),(infinity, 1))' AS overlap;
overlap 
---------
f
```

The two exemples below works

```
SELECT box '((1,1),(4, 1))' && box '((2, 1),(infinity, 1))' AS overlap;
overlap 
---------
t


SELECT box '((1,1),(4, 1))' && box '((2, 1),(5, 1))' AS overlap;
overlap
---------
t
```

So my question is : Is there something i'm doing wrong or that i don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the postgresql buglist:

Tom lane gave me this answer :

The test for this involves

```
FPge(box1->high.x, box2->high.x)
```

where FPge is defined as

```
#define FPge(A,B)    ((B) - (A) <= EPSILON)
```

When both high.x values are infinity, you have infinity minus infinity,
which yields NaN in IEEE arithmetic, so the comparison to epsilon comes
out false.

In general I don't think we promise that geometric operations involving
infinite endpoints will behave sanely.  There are probably a boatload
of corner cases besides this one that'd need to be fixed before we
could consider that a supported case.