# Exclusion constraint with overlapping timestamp range

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I would like to have an equivalent of this:

```sql
create table t (
    fromts timestamptz, 
    tots timestamptz,
    exclude using gist ((fromts, tots) with overlaps)
);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 4:         exclude using gist ((fromts, tots) with overlaps)
```

I guess that in addition to the syntax error there is also the problem of the not commutative operator.

What is the simplest way to make it work?

Comment: `timestampz`? You mean `timestamptz`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PostgreSQL` needs a named type and an operator class for the exclusion constraints to work. In `9.1`, `RANGE` is not implemented yet.

You can define your own, but this requires a super privilege (i. e. won't work on hosted databases etc.)

You can try casting the timestamps to boxes and define the constraint using intersects operator (`&&`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ts_to_box(TIMESTAMPTZ, TIMESTAMPTZ)
RETURNS BOX
AS
$$
    SELECT  BOX(POINT(DATE_PART('epoch', $1), -1), POINT(DATE_PART('epoch', $2), 1))
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TABLE t (
    fromts timestamptz, 
    tots timestamptz,
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (ts_to_box(fromts, tots) WITH &&)
);
```

Comment: This works great except with infinite or null timestamp. If you have to deal with this case go with the temporal extension : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616099/postgres-date-overlapping-constraint. You can see here why it doesn't work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642646/overlapping-box-with-infinite-edge-coordinate

Answer (score 4):

This may seem contrived at first, but it works out of the box (no pun intended):

As @Quassnoi helped me to find out, this only works for `timestamp`, not for `timestamptz`:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    fromts timestamp, 
    tots   timestamp,
    exclude using GIST (box(point(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM fromts), 0)
                          , point(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM tots),   0)) WITH &&)
);
```

My tests were with `timestamp` - before you clarified the type. `EXTRACT` is `IMMUTABLE` with `timestamp`, but not with `timestamptz`. @Quassnoi posted a hypothesis as to why that is in the comments below.

So, for `timestamp with time zone`, you have to make the conversion `IMMUTABLE` by using an auxiliary function like @Quassnoi demonstrates in his answer.

#### In Postgres 9.2 or later

... you can use the newly introduced [**range types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html), `tstzrange` for this particular case.
[The manual provides a full code example with an exclusion constraint.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT)

Comment: `ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Comment: @Quassnoi: It is. I tested this solution with Postgres 9.1 before posting. I also have a working implementation with it. Simplifeid a bit.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: it does not work on my installation as well as on sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Just re-tested on PostgreSQL 9.1.2 and it works for me. With a temporary table just as well as with a plain table. **Ah** I got it. My test was with `timestamp`, not with `timestamptz`. Oddly enough it makes a difference! My test fails as well with `timestamptz`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: on my `PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1), 64-bit` it does not work. `DATE` functions on `timestamptz` are strict but not immutable.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: `TZ` functions depend on the session zone parameter, that's why it is I believe. I thought that maybe `EXTRACT` does some magic with `EPOCH` which would make it immutable, but seems it does not.

Comment: Consider this [demo with timestamp on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a623c). If you change to `timestamptz`, it fails. Makes me wonder. But I am out of time right now ..

Comment: @Quassnoi: I think you already found the explanation. Chapeau! I'll amend my answer.